# Grouping variably contiguous timestamped records with spacing threshold

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a sequence of intermittently spaced GPS coordinates with timestamps.  I'm using PostGIS to render them onto a map canvas.  To render them, the points need to be aggregated into lines using the ST_MakeLine() aggregate function in PostGIS, leaving gaps on the map where GPS data is missing.  The data does not necessarily arrive in order from the devices.

An example sequence looks like this:

```
ID | Timestamp              | Location
--------------------------------------
1  | 2013-11-12 03:31:31    | (1,2)   
3  | 2013-11-12 03:31:34    | (1,3)   
7  | 2013-11-12 03:31:37    | (1,4)  
4  | 2013-11-12 03:31:43    | (1,5)   
2  | 2013-11-12 03:31:55    | (1,6)   
16 | 2013-11-12 03:33:22    | (1,7)   
22 | 2013-11-12 03:33:28    | (1,8)   
18 | 2013-11-12 03:33:32    | (1,9)
```

The conditions for grouping are:

- If the gap to the previous record is > 30 seconds OR
- If the time since the first record in this group < 15 seconds.  In this case, the point belongs in both groups (i.e. one group ends with this point, the next group begins)

The ST_MakeLine() function in PostGIS will produce the necessary line, the problem is properly grouping the lines.

Based on that, the above would produce:

```
Start               | End                 | ST_MakeLine(?)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-11-12 03:31:31 | 2013-11-12 03:31:43 | LINE((1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5))
2013-11-12 03:31:43 | 2013-11-12 03:31:55 | LINE((1,5),(1,6))
2013-11-12 03:33:22 | 2013-11-12 03:33:32 | LINE((1,7),(1,8),(1,9))
```

This seems to be a variation on the "island and gaps" problem referenced by most other "contiguous select" questions, but with the twist that the sequencing is not regular, and thus, those solutions don't seem to apply.

I'm currently processing the data outside SQL to generate the sequences, but that incurs several round-trips that I'd like to avoid if I can.

SQLFiddle of the sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ff93/7

Comment: Are you looking for a simple query or are you open to PL/pgSQL (With PL/pgSQL you can group a block of computation and a series of queries inside the database server, thus having the power of a procedural language and the ease of use of SQL, but with considerable savings of client/server communication overhead.) See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: A standalone query is preferable, but a procedure would work in a pinch.  Performance is the deciding factor.

Comment: Are your conditions for grouping correct? I'm having problems seeing ID 1 and ID 3 in the same group if the conditions both require `>` so many seconds. Do you mean `<`?

Comment: Yes, `<` would read better, updated.  The intent is that sequential groups of coordinates should be broken up into 15 second blocks, with a shared end/start coordinate (`(1,5)` in the example).

Comment: That explains the first group. Timestamps of `31:31` to `31:46` belong in that group and ID `4` starts the next group, but ID `2` is not repeated because the time is `>` 30 until the next record?

Comment: That's correct.

The reasoning is because of how the data is rendered on the map.  The lines are rendered on a map with different colours, depending on their age.

When I get several minutes of good data from the GPS units (i.e. no >30 second gaps), that data needs to be split into segments, and each segment is drawn with a slightly different colour.  The segments need to share a end/start point so that they touch and there is no visible gap.

If the time gap is >30 seconds, then there is no shared end/start point and the rendered line is drawn with a visible gap.

Comment: why isnt `(1,8)` shown in `LINE((1,7),(1,9))` ?

Comment: Typo, it should be.  Fixed.

Comment: it would be so much easier if there wasnt repeatables location, e.g. (1,5) which is repeated twice. For example `(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)` and
`(1,5),(1,6)` and 
`(1,7),(1,8),(1,9)` only.

Comment: Yeah, no kidding.  Unfortunately, it creates spaces on the final rendering that are unacceptable.

Comment: What do you mean that the data arrives "out of order"?  Has it not all arrived?  Are the timestamps more important than the ids?  Note that SQL states that rows in a table have no inherent ordering _anyways_ (which is the whole point of the `ORDER BY` statement - indices are an optimization feature).  If you don't really care about `id`, then this is (sort of) simplified - you only have one condition: groups can't be more than 15 seconds long, and start where the last one ended (only valid with 2+ points).  This is why I ignore ids for pretty much anything but joins (order **not** a guarantee)

Comment: I mention it because the ID's aren't in order, so methods that depend on id sequencing aren't applicable.

Comment: Unsure quite what you mean with the second rule. If you have data coming in (say) every 1s, then it would produce two-element line segments because 1s is < 15s, so you'd have `(a,b), (c,d)`, `(c,d), (e,f)`, `(e,f), (g,h)`, etc. Is that what you want? It doesn't seem to be from the example.

Comment: The second rule is to limit the maximum duration of a group.  I suppose another wording might be:

Group timestamps in sequence when either a >30 second gap is encountered, or >15 seconds of data is accumulated.  If the latter condition, the last point is shared by both groups.

See my earlier comment on map rendering for the reason why it needs to be this way.

Comment: The conditions for grouping are still wrong: 1) If the time since the first record in this group < 15 seconds, add it to the group. 2) Start the next group with the last element of the previous group. 3) Eliminate any groups with only 1 point. I don't see where the 30 seconds fit in. If you have a constraint that each group is a block of 15 seconds, you could never have 2 in the same group that are 30 seconds apart.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I could make it clearer.  The example data above is the definitive answer, the wording of the criteria is not simple.

I took your advice and made a stored proc.  Performance is excellent compared to doing it externally.  See below for a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking a two-part approach to solve this:

- A stored procedure that appends a "group id" to each row
- A simple aggregating query

Performance is significantly better than doing it external to the database (45s vs 2.8s)

So, given a table created by the following:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ts TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  location GEOMETRY(Point,4326)
);
```

The following function will iterate over the table and append a "group id" to each row:

```
CREATE FUNCTION group_locations(
  IN scan_start_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  IN max_time_gap INTERVAL, 
  IN max_line_duration INTERVAL)
RETURNS TABLE(
  out_geom GEOMETRY, 
  out_ts TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
  out_group_id INTEGER) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  r locations%ROWTYPE;
  gid INTEGER;
  lastts TIMESTAMP;
  startts TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  gid := 0;
  lastts := NULL;
  startts := NULL;

  FOR r IN 
    SELECT * FROM locations 
    WHERE ts > scan_start_time
    ORDER BY ts ASC
  LOOP
    out_ts := r.ts;
    out_geom := r.location;
    out_group_id := gid;

    IF startts IS NULL OR lastts IS NULL THEN
      startts := r.ts;
    ELSIF r.ts - lastts >= max_time_gap THEN
      -- If we've hit a space in our data, bump the group id up
      -- and remember the start time for this group
      gid := gid+1;
      out_group_id = gid;
      startts := r.ts;
    ELSIF r.ts - startts >= max_line_duration THEN
      -- First, emit the current row to end the group
      RETURN NEXT;
      -- Then, bump the group id and start time, we will
      -- re-emit the same row with a higher group_id below
      gid := gid+1;
      out_group_id := gid;
      startts := r.ts;
    END IF;
    -- Emit the current row with the group_id appended
    RETURN NEXT;
    lastts := r.ts;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

If run over my example data, the result is:

```
out_ts              | out_geom | out_group_id
---------------------------------------------
2013-11-12 03:31:31 | (1,2)    | 0
2013-11-12 03:31:34 | (1,3)    | 0
2013-11-12 03:31:37 | (1,4)    | 0
2013-11-12 03:31:43 | (1,5)    | 0
2013-11-12 03:31:43 | (1,5)    | 1
2013-11-12 03:31:55 | (1,6)    | 1
2013-11-12 03:33:22 | (1,7)    | 2
2013-11-12 03:33:28 | (1,8)    | 2
2013-11-12 03:33:32 | (1,9)    | 2
```

Then, the output of this procedure can be simply grouped and aggregated:

```
SELECT ST_Makeline(out_geom) AS geom,MIN(out_ts) AS start,MAX(out_ts) AS finish
FROM group_locations(
       NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - '10 days'::INTERVAL,  -- how far back to look
       '30 seconds'::INTERVAL,  -- maximum gap allowed before creating a break
       '15 seconds'::INTERVAL  -- maximum duration allowed before forcing a break
)
GROUP BY out_group_id;
```

The function executes quite quickly, at least an order of magnitude better than doing the same logic externally.  The downside is that the results are not indexed, so directly using them in further queries is not particularly performant.  It runs in about O(2N) time, the first scan to append the group ID, then the second scan to aggregate.

My final solution executes the above every couple of minutes to refresh a "calculated_tracks" table which is fully indexed.