# Extract individual lines from a gps track that runs in a loop

Tags: postgis, qgis, gpx

I have a gps track that I imported into postgis. The track ran in a loop for around 8 hours and so the resulting table contains only one record though it shows several lines in QGIS. I would like to cut the track into several records, one record per loop. So far I have employed the st_intersection & st_intersects using a polygon that looks like a donut (with a gap) cutting the lines at its ends.

Below is the script (from [here](http://selectoid.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/a-look-at-st_intersects-st_overlaps-and-st_intersection/)) I used to get the tracklines within the boundary polygon:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
AS (SELECT st_intersection(brte.st_union, trk.geom_32651)
    FROM buffer35 AS brte,
        tracks_utmz51n AS trk
    WHERE st_intersects(brte.st_union, trk.geom_32651)); 

ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;
ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Still the table shows only one record even though the lines already start and end same as the donut. Is there an explode function (like in autocad) in postgis? The solution suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21648/explode-multilinestring-into-individual-segments-in-postgis-1-5) explodes it into point-to-point segments.

I'd like to try the code below (from Lhttp://amercader.net/blog/2011/04/exploding-multigeometries-with-postgis ~returns a set of the individual geometries that make up a multi one). If mpoly is for polygons, what is it for lines so I can substitute it?:

```
CREATE TABLE world_worldborders_3 AS
SELECT id,name,
(ST_Dump(mpoly)).geom
FROM world_worldborders;
```

ADDITIONAL WORKFLOW DETAILS:

1. I have a GPX track from a vehicle that ran 8 hours around a predefined route. This being a loop, the vehicle passes the same areas at different times. This was intended because I am trying to study travel time differences per hour.
2. Using OGR2OGR I import the track(as is/default settings) unto a postgis database. The result is 6 tables, of which I only keep the tracklines and the trackpoints then discard the rest. I convert this to EPSG32651 from EPSG4326
3. I initially intended to just work with the trackpoints and discard the tracklines as well, but the dilemma was, since it was in a loop, I couldn't just pick-out the points at the start and end of a road segment because there are other pairs on the same segment but at a different time interval. So maybe after 30-40 minutes, the vehicle passes then I have another start and end time at that segment.
4. I need to be able to differentiate the pairs. The trackline per loop, I thought would help since that would serve as an ID for the pairs. ex. This pair from Loop#1 and so on.
5. That's why I removed a small portion out of the route line, buffered the remaining in order to catch the tracklines then tried running the st_intersects & st_intersection thinking that it would cut the trackline into the loops I needed. Unfortunately, the output was a multiline. If I click on one loop, the rest are also selected.
6. The solutions I've found so far used a pl/pgsql script. I cannot do that (I think) because this is a python class project. I'm basically running the postgis script through psycopg2 so I'm looking for a straightforward script.
7. If there's really no way to try and break-up the trackline into several tracklines (1 per loop) with postgis, I guess I'll have to use ST_MAKELINE after I have made a loop identifier(to group by) with just python like discussed in Lhttp://www.bostongis.com/postgis_makeline.snippet ..something..something..or just do everthing with just python and a list of dictionaries containing the track points information.

Any ideas? Is there any other way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The query to explode multilinestrings in individual linestrings is the same as for multipolygons. In your case would be:

```
SELECT id,(ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom FROM test;
```

Note that, in this query, "the_geom" is the name of the geometry column of the table "test" and must be change if you named the geometry column different. "geom" is the name of the geometry field of the dump object and must not be changed.

PS: actually the geometry column of your test table is named "st_intersections". It would be better to explicitly give a name to this column using a alias. Just change your select statement so:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
AS (SELECT st_intersection(brte.st_union, trk.geom_32651) AS the_geom
    FROM buffer35 AS brte, .......
```

Comment: Hi! I did as you discussed although the output was not as I expected it to be. I need to have the number of lines/records to be the same as the number of loops. So if it ran 10 times around the block, the output lines should also be 10. The output was several hundred records. Upon closer inspection, the reason was due to the lines being cut at the intersections, including self-intersections. Do you have another way to go about this? Anyway, I do thank you for pointing that out. I'm actually new to postgis and what I do (shamefacedly) is try to synthesize from codes i find online.

Comment: I saw the solution given at 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929022/grouping-variably-contiguous-timestamped-records-with-spacing-threshold 2. www.agile-online.org/Conference_Paper/cds/agile.../agile2014_91.pdf. If there is no short postgis script, I would probably end-up with using python for this part.

Comment: ....also..as much as I would like to click the up-vote, I can't because it requires 15 rep..I really appreciate your helping me out =)

Comment: Try to explain better what are you trying to do. I.e I assume, you store a single multilinestring in the database and want only to expand it to individual linestrings. Is this all correct? Why do you use the st_intersection and st_intesects with a "donut" polygon? This is not necessary to expand multilinestring to individual linestrings. Maybe can you post a extract of the data in you table tracks_utmz51n

Comment: Both the geom_32651 & the wkb_geometry are blanks when I look at this in postgis but in QGIS, the wkb_geometry has the following: SRID=4326;MULTILINESTRING((121.065206 14.657575,121.065206 14.657575,121.065175 14.657585,121.065114 14.657598,121.065065 14.657598,121.065041 14.657619,121.064999 14.657602,121.064956 14.657609,121.064903 14.657614,121.064836 14.657593,121.064817 14.657588,121.064787 14.657601,121.064736 14.657605,121.064686 14.65762,121.064656 14.657624, etc......

Comment: Ok I think I understand now the problem but I can still not suggest you a solution without sample data. I guess, you need some complex spatial query to identify the single paths. May can you share a dump of your relevant postgres tables (or a extract from them) using dropbox or something else?

Comment: Hi! That's ok, I decided to just continue the next processes outside of postgis (as a list of dictionaries) so that I could immediately include output of computations as dictionary values. Super thanks for taking the time to help me out =)